# Disabling Services via Powershell for computer management

Tags: powershell

My code here should disable services in the list. But I get an error that

```
method invocation failed because system string doesn't contain a a method named ChangeStartMode
```

`(gwmi win32_service -filter "name = 'SharedAccess' Or name = 'cx2Svc' OR name = 'NetTcpPortSharing' OR name = 'RemoteAccess' OR name = 'AxInstSV' OR name = 'SensrSvc' OR name = 'ALG' OR name = 'AppMgmt' OR name = 'BDESVC' OR name = 'bthserv' OR name = 'PeerDistSvc' OR name = 'CertPropSvc' OR name = 'VaultSvc' OR name = 'DPS' OR name = 'WdiServiceHost' OR name = 'WdiSystemHost' OR name = 'TrkWks' OR name = 'EFS' OR name = 'Fax' OR name = 'fdPHost' OR name = 'FDResPub' OR name = 'hkmsvc' OR name = 'hidserv' OR name = 'UI0Detect' OR name = 'iphlpsvc' OR name = 'lltdsvc' OR name = 'MSiSCSI' OR name = 'Netlogon' OR name = 'napagent' OR name = 'CscService' OR name = 'WPCSvc' OR name = 'PNRPsvc' OR name = 'p2psvc' OR name = 'p2pimsvc' OR name = 'IPBusEnum' OR name = 'PNRPAutoReg' OR name = 'WPDBusEnum' OR name = 'wercplsupport' OR name = 'PcaSvc'").ChangeStartMode("Disabled")`

I have tried changing the quoting and tried making it one service. I also tried using ChangeServiceStart and ChangeServiceStartType which I found online for other people's scripts but none of those worked. I have also tried this on several computers in powershell v1.0 v2.0 and one with WMI 3.0

Comment: Are you sure The command given here is what you are trying? It works as expected for me. Can you give the exact simplified case of the one you tried with just one service?

Comment: (gwmi win32_service -filter "name = 'SharedAccess'").ChangeStartMode("Disabled")
Am I structuring this correctly?

Comment: Also I used a USB wrote it to a text file and have been copy/pasting it when trying it or posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use foreach or ForEach-Object to call that method for each result returned -

Simplified example using ForEach-Object -

```
(gwmi win32_service -filter "name = 'SharedAccess' Or name = 'cx2Svc') | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.ChangeStartMode("Disabled")}
```

You could also use the service cmdlets for this activity -

```
Get-Service -Name SharedAccess, cx2Svc -EA 0 | 
   Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.